# How do I validate an RSA SSH public key file (id_rsa.pub)?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, rsa

Is there a command I can use to verify the public key (id_rsa.pub), just the **format** only.

Sometimes I have added a new linebreak, sometimes the file missed the `ssh-rsa` prefix, so is there a command to validate with?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can use `ssh-keygen` for this. Despite its name it can do many more things than generating keys:

```
dennis@lightning:~$ ssh-keygen -l -f .ssh/id_rsa.pub 
2048 68:df:b2:22:d8:43:5d:36:75:c1:d8:59:c0:8c:22:e8  Dennis Kaarsemaker (RSA)
dennis@lightning:~$ ssh-keygen -l -f foo.txt
foo.txt is not a public key file.
```

Comment: So I have to have the fingerprint beforehand to validate the public key?

Comment: @QuaziIrfan no, you do not need the fingerprint beforehand. The returncode of `ssh-keygen` will tell you whether it's valid or not.

Comment: Does not work for keys with passwords :-(

Comment: Note that this also works on a file containing multiple keys, such as `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: @QuaziIrfan the fingerprint is the output of the "ssh-keygen -l" output, which is to show fingerprint of the given pub/pri key file

Comment: Note that ssh-keygen will also accept options before ssh-xxx (as in authorized_keys), which can potentially be dangerous: command="xxx", ...

Comment: The `[-E fingerprint_hash]` option is also useful if you want something other than the default, e.g. `-E md5` or `-E sha512`